# Is there a way to remove page number text object from a PDF via Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to remove a page number text object from each page of a PDF I automate each month. I have been able to run a python script to create the final PDF I need, but am unable to automatically remove the incorrect page numbers and replace with new page nums in the correct order (as I have to piece this PDF together from multiple source PDFs.

Any thoughts on best way to complete this?

Comment: These resources might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144293 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346942

Comment: Thanks. These links basically say it's extremely hard or not worth it. Is there any new ways since these links were posted? Just need to delete 1 small specific text within the pdfs pages.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get a solution to the problem? I am facing a similar issue and need to find a way to delete text from pdf.